# Flex 4.5 Mobile Development

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, api, adobe, flex4.5

I recently started developing mobile applications using Flex 4.5 with the help of a book, but was unable to find the API documentation for the same from Adobe.

Does anyone know where I can find the mobile development API documentation from Adobe ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mobile development using Flex 4.5 , you can find the [`Documentation`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/index.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

The standard API docs for Actionscript 3 can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html). This will show you a much larger set of components than just the mobile ones. To see what components you should be using for mobile you can look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSf3db6597adcd110e19124fcb12ab3a1c319-8000.html).